# Stretching ListView columns

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm new to WPF. I'm developing an application which contains a list view control. I have added 5 columns to it but the problem is these five columns are not stretched in the list view control.

```
   <ListView Grid.Column="2" Name="d" Margin="0,0,0,23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="d" Width="100" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="d" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="d" Width="100" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="d" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="d" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="d"  Width="100"/>
                </GridView>
           </ListView.View>

        </ListView>
```

Here is the code that I used. I tried to put * for as width in columns but it not acceptable.  How am I to stretch this columns in list view control?

Comment: What do you mean by stretched? Are your 6 columns not filling the entire width of the ListView?

Comment: Check out http://www.ontheblog.net/CMS/Home/tabid/36/EntryID/37/Default.aspx  or http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/83bd7ab9-3407-461f-a0bc-69e04870075c/